# Scraping all h1 tags contents with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape some review data with beautiful soup, and it will only let me grab a single element:

```
BASE_URL = "http://consequenceofsound.net/'category/reviews/album-reviews/"
html = urlopen(BASE_URL + section_url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
meta = soup.find("div", {"class": "content"}).h1
wordage = [s.contents for s in meta]
```

this will let me grab a single reviews title from this page.  When I change find to find_all though, I can't identify h1 on this line, so I get some code like this:

```
meta = soup.find("div", {"class": "content"})
wordage = [s.h1 for s in meta]
```

and I'm unable to find a way to isolate the contents.

Comment: What are you expecting `wordage` to be? Also, can you show a very simple example of your html?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meta = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "content"})

wordage = [s.h1 for s in meta if s.h1 not in ([], None)]
link = [s.a['href'] for s in wordage]
```

Note the addition of the 'not in' statement.  It seems on occassion empty and nonetype lists get added in to the 'soup' so this is an important measure.